# semaphore is not getting accessed eventhough it is unlocked

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I have written a 2 programs in order to understand how to implement semaphores.

Give.c: Creates a semaphore with initial value of 1 and unlocks it

```
    /*
* Brief - This program is used to create a semaphore and "unlock" it
* 
* 
*
* Reference - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651965/how-to-open-an-existing-named-semaphore 
*/
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <semaphore.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

sem_t *semaphore;

int ret=1; 

//Thread function
void *threadFunc(void *data)
{
    
    sem_post(semaphore);

    printf("Thread:Completed execution!\n");

    pthread_exit(&ret);
}


int main()
{
    semaphore = sem_open("semaphore",O_CREAT,0644,1);

    sleep(5);

    pthread_t task; 

    pthread_create(&task,NULL,threadFunc,NULL);

    

    printf("Main: Waiting for thread to complete!\n");
    pthread_join(task,NULL);
    printf("Main: Exiting now!\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Take.c: Opens a semaphore and tries to access it. But, has to wait until it is released by Give.c

```
/*
* Brief - This program is used to open a semaphore and "read" or "lock" it.
*       - However, it has to wait until the semaphore has been unlocked by "Give.c"
* 
* 
*
* Reference - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651965/how-to-open-an-existing-named-semaphore 
*/
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <semaphore.h> 

sem_t *semaphore;

int ret=1; 

//Thread function
void *threadFunc(void *data)
{

    printf("Thread: Waiting for semaphore to be unlocked\n");
    sem_wait(semaphore);

    printf("Thread:Completed execution!\n");

    pthread_exit(&ret);
}


int main()
{

    pthread_t task; 

    semaphore = sem_open("semaphore",0);

    pthread_create(&task,NULL,threadFunc,NULL);

    sleep(5);

    printf("Main: Waiting for thread to complete!\n");
    pthread_join(task,NULL);
    printf("Main: Exiting now!\n");

    return 0;

}
```

First, I execute give.c which creates and initializes the semaphore with the value of 1.
Within 5 seconds (NOTE: give.c sleeps for 5 seconds), I run Take.c. However, it still waits for Give.c to unlock the semaphore. Why is this happening? The initial value being 1, should already unlock the semaphore right? My expectation from this was that Take.c should not wait for semaphore to be released as it is initialized with 1.

Please share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "If O_CREAT is specified, and a semaphore with the given name already exists, then mode and value are ignored." BTW you don't need threads for this demo.

Comment: Hey @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.
I didn't quite understand your reply. Can you please elaborate? 

O_CREAT is used in Give.c right. When I execute Give.c first, it would create a semaphore file with initial value of 1 right? 
Then, when take.C tries to access it, it should be access it because initial value is 1.

Comment: When you run the pogram for the first time, the semaphore is created with the value of 1. When you run it for the second time, the semaphore is already there, and the value is ignored. Use `sem_unlink` when you are done with the semaphore.

Comment: Your semaphore name does not have the expected form; see [`sem_overview(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html).  This might or might not be related to your issue.

Comment: You do not test for failures of any of your function calls.  It is entirely possible that that the unexpected behavior is related to detectable function failures that you are ignoring.

Comment: And, as @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. observed first, you don't need threads for this.  They are just confusing the issue, so get rid of them.  Run the semaphore operations in your `main()` functions.

Comment: semaphore name should start with a "/". So instead of "semaphore", try "/semaphore".